# How to use disk cache to cache ParseFile

Tags: android, parse-platform, picasso

I'm using Parse and Picasso to load images onto ParseImageViews. Is there anything I'm missing to cache the parse files? My listview seems to be fetching the file from server every time and using the disk cache that comes with Picasso.

I don't see cache-control: max-age parameter in the http responses of downloads of parse files(from amazon s3 where parse stores them)

I have the following code,

```
    final ParseImageView pic = viewHolder.img;
    pic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    ParseFile f = parseObject.getParseFile("image");
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(f.getUrl()).into(pic);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: save it to stoarage?

Comment: @Elltz, what did u mean by that? Sorry, I'm new to Parse

Comment: what i mean is you have the `parseFile` `f` so save it to your internal storage and when you need it you retrieve it no need to go to the web again

Answer (score 0):

Use OkHttp client as http transport for Picasso and specify disk and memory cache size:

```
OkHttpClient okHttp = new OkHttpClient();

Cache cache = new Cache(ctx.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);

okHttp.setCache(cache);

// Use OkHttp as downloader
Downloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(okHttp);

mPicasso = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext())
  .downloader(downloader)).memoryCache(new LruCache(size)).build();
```

Setup request interceptor (example) for OkHttp client:

```
// Add Cache-Control to origin response (force cache)
 client.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {

    private com.squareup.okhttp.Request request;
    private Response response;
    private String requestUrl;

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain c) throws IOException {
        request = c.request();

        response = c.proceed(request);

        if (!request.cacheControl().noStore()
               && !response.cacheControl().noStore()) {

        requestUrl = request.urlString();

        // Do not cache keys or playlists

           response = response
            .newBuilder()
            .header("Cache-Control","public, max-age=42000").build();

        }

         return response;
     }
   });
```